# How to browse a sd card and select an audio file to be played in android app?

Tags: android

I want to browse sd card for listing all the audio files and select one to play.Someone could help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an example of [file browser](http://www.anddev.org/android_filebrowser__v20-t101.html).

Here is an example of [Audio playing](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-play-video-and-audio-android)